# Codeigniter Custom Classes

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I was wondering if I could have more than one custom class in CodeIgniter 3? I currently have a custom class called AC_Controller which extends the CI_Controller.

I have put this in my config

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoload Custom Controllers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
function __autoload($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'AC_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php')) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows my AC_Controller to load but when I add another controller called AC_Repeat and reference it in a controller, I get this error Fatal error: Class 'AC_Repeat' not found.

So did I do something wrong or is only one custom class allowed?

Comment: Is your AC_repeat.php class file saved in `core/`? [According to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29806207/3585500), CI would load the AC_Controller class automatically anyway if you told it the prefix was AC_ in the config, but not the AC_Repeat because it's not a core class name it knows.

Comment: Yeah they're all in core.

Comment: It surprisingly loads if I place the contents of AC_Repeat in AC_Controller

Comment: [Here's an article covering 4 methods to autoload your own classes](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/). Option 2 covers this method but it looks different. It's also from May 2015, so things may have changed. The official CI way (I guess) is to use hooks.